# Trying to print a div retaining original css content of the div but button is not clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print a div retaining original css content of the div and here is my attempt

**JS :**

```
function printDiv(id) {

      var html = "";

      $('link').each(function() { // find all <link tags that have
        if ($(this).attr('rel').indexOf('stylesheet') !=-1) { // rel="stylesheet"
          html += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+$(this).attr("href")+'" />';
        }
      });
      html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">+$("#"+id).html()+'</body>';
      var w = window.open("","print");
      if (w) { w.document.write(html); w.document.close() }

    }

$('#PrintinPopup').click(function(){ printDiv("#print"); });
```

Assuming that this is the div content.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="print">
    <!--div content here-->
</div>
<input type="button" id="PrintinPopup" value="Print" />
```

On clicking the button, nothing happens as no pop up is shown on the window. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

Comment: Look at the html += line in the editor above.... see the color coding issue??

Comment: cannot find any....... which line please

Comment: `html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">+$("#"+id).html()+'</body>';`

Comment: so what is the problem with this line

Comment: Look at it.....

Comment: please what am I missing cannot find any

Comment: It is not valid string... Follow the opening and closing `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a missing quote in :

```
html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">+$("#"+id).html()+'</body>';
______________________________________________________^^
```

It should be :

```
html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">'+$("#"+id).html()+'</body>';
_______________________________________________________^
```

Also remove the '#' since you already send it in the call `printDiv("#print")` :

```
html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">'+$("#"+id).html()+'</body>';
___________________________________________________________^^^^
```

Should be :

```
html += '<body onload="window.focus(); window.print()">'+$(id).html()+'</body>';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##print

Comment: this is the error I am getting on implementing your solution

Comment: yeah, but its not retaining css. how can I make it to retain css

Comment: Try to use `@media print` take a look to https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/tips-and-tricks-for-print-style-sheets/

Comment: can u show a simple snippet with @media print based on my solution

Comment: Try in your stylesheet a simple example `@media print { #print{ color: blue; } }`.